# nuget.org - Create Remote Feed in Artifactory

Tags: nuget, artifactory

I would like to create an Artifactory remote feed for nuget.org following the [official instruction](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/NuGet+Repositories):

Feed Name: nuget-remote
URL: https://www.nuget.org/
Repository Layout:  nuget-default
NuGet Download Context Path: api/v2/package
NuGet Feed Context Path: api/v2
NuGet v3 Feed URL: https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

Built-in test function completed during the feed creation however the list of the packages are not available and nuget client is not able to connect to the service:

```
PM> find-package 
find-package : The following source failed to search for packages: 'nuget.org-artifactory-remote'
Unable to load the service index for source https://FQDN/api/nuget/nuget-remote.
  Response status code does not indicate success: 503 (Service Unavailable).

PM> Install-Package elmah
Install-Package : Unable to find package 'elmah' at source ''.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package elmah
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageComma 
   nd
 
Time Elapsed: 00:00:01.1222016
```

Regards,
Gabor

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIpxv.png)

Comment: Do you have other remote feeds set up besides the one you've shown us?

Comment: The default feed (nuget.org) has been removed from the nuget.config.    
I did not faced same issue on other Artifactory's remote feeds.

Comment: @iambernics Were you able to find the solution for this? I'm experiencing the same issue and was wondering if you had a solution.